# Using match with letters and a variable

Tags: regex, perl, match

I provide some variables and try using them for matching with the input, but I have problems matching how I want to match.

```
my $x = 1.0;

foreach ( @data ) { # see sample data below

    my $input = $_; # I know, I know...

    if ( $input =~ m/ph${x}/ ) {
        print "$input \n"; 
    }
}
```

#### Input (content of @data):

```
info.ph1.0.dat_0
info.ph1.5.dat_1
info.ph2.0.dat_2
```

#### Output:

```
info.ph1.0.dat_0 
info.ph1.5.dat_1
```

#### The desired output is

```
info.ph1.0.dat_0
```

`$x` will always be something like `1.0`, `1.1`, `1.2` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1. You need to quote the string literal `1.0` as Nullman [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430621/82262)
2. You need to properly [quote any metacharacters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters) contained inside `$x`. For example, do you want `info.ph1x0.dat_0` or `info.ph1*0.dat_0` to also match? Well, they will, because the unescaped dot in `1.0` matches any character.

Revised code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $x = '1.0';

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/ph\Q$x/) {
        say;
    }
}

__DATA__
info.ph1.0.dat_0
info.ph1.5.dat_1
info.ph2.0.dat_2
info.ph1x0.dat_0
info.ph1*0.dat_0
```

Output:

```
info.ph1.0.dat_0
```

Comment: It would be nice if you would explain your `use 5.010`

Answer (score 0):

probably this bit:

`my $x = 1.0;`

should be

`my $x = '1.0';`

this happens because perl saves `1.0` as `1`

Comment: Although it would be better if I could avoid using $x = '1.0'

Comment: @ChemistryandComputers Better in what way? This is starting to sound like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ChemistryandComputers: You need to explain why you would prefer to avoid the quotes. There are probably many ways around this, but we can't really help you without understanding your situation. Perhaps you should answer a new question about it.